# How can I deduce the type and its template arguments for a meta-function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

Suppose I have a meta-function which requires both the type *and* its arguments. How can I do this without forcing the user of the function to provide both the type and its arguments separately?

```
using MyType = SomeType<T1, T2, T3>; // This is the type to pass to the functor

template <typename MyType, typename ... Args>
struct MetaFunction
{
  using type = SomeOperation<MyType, Args...>;
}

// I want to be able to call my functor like this:
MetaFunction<MyType>::type;

// but with the above I have to call it like this:
MetaFunction<MyType, T1, T2, T3>::type;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Like this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e35f4d9ee42fba5

Comment: @dyp. Yup! Can you post that as the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "disassemble" a class template specialization into the template itself and the template parameters by using *partial spezialiation* (some form of pattern-matching).

First, we define `MetaFunction` to be a (class) template that takes a *type* as its only parameter:

```
template <typename T>
struct MetaFunction;
```

Then, we define a *partial specialization* of this class template `MetaFunction`. A partial specialization is a special case of a class template. If the case applies, the partial specialization is used instead of the original (primary) template to make a class. The template "interface", i.e. the amount and kind of template arguments you can/must provide to instantiate the `MetaFunction` template is not changed by the existence of specializations.

A partial specialization, as opposed to an *explicit specialization*, is also a template, which implies that it has template parameters. The *partial* means that it does not specify *fully* for which types (sets of template arguments) it applies as a special case. Typically, partial specializations apply to subsets of the set of possible/valid arguments you can supply to the primary template.

```
template <template<typename...> class TT, typename ... Args>
struct MetaFunction /* not finished yet */
```

There are three kinds of template parameters:

- Type parameters
- "Value" parameters (non-type)
- Template parameters

This partial specialization uses a template *template-parameter*. A valid argument for such a parameter must be a either a class template or an alias template.

We specify when this partial specialization shall be used by providing a "pattern":

```
template <template<typename...> class TT, typename ... Args>
struct MetaFunction<TT<Args...>>
{
  using type = SomeOperation<TT, Args...>;
};
```

This partial specialization will be used if the type supplied to the `MetaFunction` template matches the pattern `TT<Args...>`, i.e., if it can be disassembled into a class<strike>/alias</strike><sup>(*)</sup> template `TT` and some template *type* parameters `Args`.

<sup>(*)</sup> As [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) correctly noted, a type produced via an *alias-template* is not associated with the alias-template. Therefore, you cannot deduce an alias-template from a type.

Comment: Since partial specialization matching uses template argument deduction, IIRC it will not use alias templates.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, right. Somehow I didn't see the comment notification, or it was not correctly delivered :(